# how to fix AAD login error in MVC controller

Tags: iis, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get the user to login with their AAD credential so that i can retrieve their AuthenticationResult UserInfo.

I am seeing this error on IIS 10: 
**azure active directory error Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation**

In my MVC controller, I have this code :

```
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        try
        {
            result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always)).Result;
```

This worked fine locally , with a AAD window popping up.

Thanks,Peter

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you couldn't show dialog box ON SERVER from ASP.NET application, since this dialog is showing on the server not in the browser.

In asp.net MVCapplication , you could redirect user to the azure ad login page to let user input credentials instead of show dialog box.

Details, you could refer to below test demo codes:

```cs
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCNormallIssue.Controllers
{
    public class AADAuthController : Controller
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
        private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];

        public static readonly string Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

        // GET: AADAuth
        public ActionResult Index()
        {


            if (Request.Params["code"] != null)
            {
                var accesstoken = AcquireTokenWithResource(resource: "https://graph.microsoft.com/");

                Response.Write(accesstoken);
            }
            else
            {
                GetAuthorizationCode();
            }
            //AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
            //    AuthenticationResult result = null;
            //    Uri uri = new Uri(redirectUri);
            //   result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", clientId, uri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always)).Result;

            return View();
        }

        public void GetAuthorizationCode()
        {
            JObject response = new JObject();

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "response_type", "code" },
                    { "client_id", clientId },
                    { "redirect_uri", "http://localhost:51939/AADAuth/index" },
                    { "prompt", "login"},
                    { "scope", "openid"}
                };

            var requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/authorize?{1}", EndPointUrl, BuildQueryString(parameters));

            Response.Redirect(requestUrl);

        }


        public string AcquireTokenWithResource(string resource)
        {
            var code = Request.Params["code"];
            AuthenticationContext ac =
        new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenant
                                  ));
            ClientCredential clcred =
                new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            var token =
                ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code,
                           new Uri("http://localhost:51939/AADAuth/index"), clcred, resource).Result.AccessToken;

            return token;
        }


        private string BuildQueryString(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            var list = new List<string>();

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                list.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", parameter.Key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameter.Value)));
            }

            return string.Join("&", list);
        }

        protected string EndPointUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", "https://login.microsoftonline.com", tenant, @"oauth2/");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the info !
What does "code" contain? does code decide which path to follow - based on running a debugger in Visual Studio  vs   running remotely  on the IIS server ?

Comment: ok, I figured out that code is a value returned by the postback from the AAD auth.

Comment: Yes, the code is the openid connected return value which is used to generate the access token.